# Aws Dynamo Time Series Read Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, time-series, amazon-dynamodb

What would be the best way to model a time series data, that needs fast lookup for single items, however writes are not important.

```
columns: Time(PK), value
```

`Time` will be stored as an Unix `timestamp`, `value` as an `int`.

Queries I want to perform:

- Given a timestamp, find the closest timestamp in table to that one. so no scans at all.

Writes will be periodic, maybe every hour. As long as the writes happen at some point in time, it is fine. They will be done via lambda.

Are there any pitfalls with strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DynamoDB and time series data your best option is probably to bucketize your data with a granularity that makes sense depending on the distribution of data points across time. For instance, if you only expect to receive a certain number of data points every hour, then perhaps using the date+hour of the day as a partition key and the timestamp as the sort key, would make sense.

If your data is pretty sparse throughput the day though, perhaps the partition key might be the date alone.

Either way, the principle is the same: partition your time series into chunks and the sort the data points in each chunk by the actual timestamp.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

I was thinking of having a new table for each year.

The timstamp values will be seperated by minutes, so I would write either every hour or at the end of every day.

The 2018 and 2017 tables will be used the most, in each table I am adding a new column called stockName. What I was thinking was to do stockName+Timestamp(Unix) as the partition key and hash it. Then the sort key as the timestamp.

I am not sure I would need to hash, I was thinking it would provide better partitions.

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, having rolling tables will help with optimizing access patterns for old vs new data. However, regarding partitioning - you will have to have a partition key anyway and unless you put all data in the same partition (which will scale poorly) you need to partition by hour or by day, so you can write efficient queries for data close to a given timestamp.

Comment: Regarding partitioning, I doubt my table will ever get to over 10GB for about 3 years, so the partitioning will only ever happen when I get to 3k RCU, so I will be stuck potentially with one partition for a while.

What if I was to partition the stockName and then sort on the timestamp?

I am not sure dynamo has the capability, but for timestamp If it is not available in the table, i may need to get the closest one.

Thanks again for the help, Mike

Comment: You can certainly partition on stock name. Assuming you will have the same number of data point for each stock that would be pretty uniform. And if you are not concerned about exceeding provisioned throughput for reading then that could work. You will have to write separate queries for each stock if you partition by stock name.

Comment: I am currently looking to set my RCU at 200/300, which should be fine for a while I believe.

Since reading is relatively cheap, I do not mind exceeding it, but due to traffic and not due to bad design

I should theoretically have the same number of datapoints for each stock.

Why would this lead to a exceeding in RCU?

Comment: I think you are absolutely right to batch your writes. You should have your writes spaced out over the hour and try to consume your available capacity as close to 100% as possible. 300 WCU may be more then you need, unless you plan on writing more than 1,000,000 data points per hour. For instance, if you will only be writing 100,000 data points per hour then perhaps 30-40 WCU is enough. Just have a process that writes every 5 minutes to take advantage of burst capacity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164286/discussion-between-kyle-graham-and-mike-dinescu).

Comment: Oops - You were talking about RCU. Yes, the read capacity should be set to whatever level is needed by your use case. Also, I would encourage you to consider cashing heavily. Since data written doesn’t change, a cache layer will be perfect and it can save you a lot of money and latency

Comment: Since a user will give me a list of stocks that they bought with a timestamp, It's kind of hard to say whether I should partition on stocks or timestamp, because I will be looking in the dynamodb table for a particular stock at a particular timestamp
Each stock will have a limited amount of timestamps per year, however, I can have in theory a lot of stocks

I checked out DAX and it seems that they are charged at an hourly rate, so I plan to see when I have the greatest traffic and deploy for a couple hours around there, increasing RCU still seems cheaper at the moment however

Comment: I was thinking to do it on the stockname, and since we have adaptive capacity, if one stock partition becomes really popular, then dynamo will send over some of the RCU from the less popular partitions to deal with it

Comment: If it was done on hour+day or any derivative or time, I would inevitably get a hot partition also because traders like to trade at particular times, maybe when a stock drops or at 4:30 every day